# setting up client affinity for db2 purescale

Tags: db2, high-availability, disaster-recovery

I have a DB2 Purescale environment set up. I am trying to configure client affinity for it on my client machine. I have modified my db2dsdriver.cfg file as follows to include the client affinity parameters:-

```
<configuration>
    <dsncollection>
        <dsn alias="sample" name="sample" host="127.0.0.0" port="50000">
            <parameter name="Authentication" value="Server"/> 
        </dsn>  
    </dsncollection>
<databases>
    <database name="sample" host="127.0.0.0" port="50000">
        <parameter name="keepAliveTimeout" value="20"/>
            <acr>
        <parameter name="enableAcr" value="true"/>
        <parameter name="enableSeamlessACR" value="true"/>
        <parameter name="maxAcrRetries" value="2"/>
        <parameter name="acrRetryInterval" value="3"/>
        <parameter name="affinityFailbackInterval" value="60"/>
        <parameter name="enableAlternateServerListFirstConnect" value="false"/>
        <alternateserverlist>
            <server name="host-1" hostname="127.0.0.0" port="50000"/>
            <server name="host-2" hostname="127.0.0.1" port="50000"/>
            <server name="host-3" hostname="127.0.0.2" port="50000"/>
        </alternateserverlist>
        <affinitylist>
            <list name="list1" serverorder="host-1,host-2,host-3">
            </list>
        </affinitylist>
        <clientaffinitydefined>
            <client name="ABC" hostname="127.0.0.3" listname="list1">
            </client>
        </clientaffinitydefined>
    </acr>
    </database>
</databases>
</configuration>
```

Please note that all the IPs and the machine names provided here are just made up.

But, when I try the db2clp to connect to my database, I get the following error:-
"SQL5163N A required configuration parameter "listname or serverorder under affinitylist group" is missing from the db2dsdriver.cfg configuration file."I have tried but cannot figure out what is missing as both the listname and the serverorder are present in the file.

Also, if I use the CLPPLUS to access the DB from client machine, I can access the DB on host-1, but if I stop the instance on host-1 to test client affinity, my client machine cannot connect to the DB on host-2. I get the following error:-
[Error when instance stopped on host-1 and running on host-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07sLX.jpg)

Can someone please help me understand what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following address:

```
    <client name="ABC" hostname="127.0.0.3" listname="list1">
    </client>
```

This must be your client's address. If it's not correct, you get such an error you mentioned.

As for CLPPLUS. It's a jdbc application, and it doesn't use db2dsdriver.cfg.
You must set the corresponding properties.

[Example of enabling client affinities in Java clients for Db2 on Linux, UNIX, and Windows systems connections.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_c0056259.html)

Comment: Yes Mark, it is  my client's address, but, I am still getting an error. Also, will definitely check the link you shared to set the properties for clpplus, but kindly let me know if you have any other idea why my db2clp is not working.

Comment: Have you tried 127.0.0.1? This must work. The same is for every your local address shown in the output of ipconfig -all / ifconfig -a.
If it doesn't work then open a Case / PMR with IBM (or double check you settings).

Comment: Yes Mark, I have tried 127.0.0.1 as well. Checking with IBM support now. Thanks.